# How acceletare logging to DB?

Tags: sql, groovy, mssql-jdbc

I have my own appender on groovy language, which writes all logging message to database. But when I use it, performance of my code falls by 25% and code runs 25% slower compared to working without this appender.

How can I accelerate this procces?

Comment: you could attempt to decouple it by queuing the logs up and write batches in a separate thread.  or use some messaging framework.

Comment: i know that [logback][1] natively supports databases and can be used with @Slf4j annotation. Perhaps that framework would speed things up and remove some complexity from your codebase
.

  [1]: http://logback.qos.ch/